# Valgrind says "stack allocation," I say "heap allocation"

Tags: c, malloc, valgrind, calloc

I am trying to trace a segfault with valgrind.  I get the following message from valgrind:

```
==3683== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==3683==    at 0x4C277C5: sparse_mat_mat_kron (sparse.c:165)
==3683==    by 0x4C2706E: rec_mating (rec.c:176)
==3683==    by 0x401C1C: age_dep_iterate (age_dep.c:287)
==3683==    by 0x4014CB: main (age_dep.c:92)
==3683==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==3683==    at 0x401848: age_dep_init_params (age_dep.c:131)
==3683== 
==3683== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==3683==    at 0x4C277C7: sparse_mat_mat_kron (sparse.c:165)
==3683==    by 0x4C2706E: rec_mating (rec.c:176)
==3683==    by 0x401C1C: age_dep_iterate (age_dep.c:287)
==3683==    by 0x4014CB: main (age_dep.c:92)
==3683==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==3683==    at 0x401848: age_dep_init_params (age_dep.c:131)
```

However, here's the offending line:

```
 /* allocate mating table */
  age_dep_data->mtable = malloc (age_dep_data->geno * sizeof (double *));
  if (age_dep_data->mtable == NULL)
    error (ENOMEM, ENOMEM, nullmsg, __LINE__);
  for (int j = 0; j < age_dep_data->geno; j++)
    {      
 131=>     age_dep_data->mtable[j] = calloc (age_dep_data->geno, sizeof (double));
      if (age_dep_data->mtable[j] == NULL)
 error (ENOMEM, ENOMEM, nullmsg, __LINE__);
    }
```

What gives?  I thought any call to malloc or calloc allocated heap space; there is no other variable allocated here, right?  Is it possible there's another allocation going on (the offending stack allocation) that I'm not seeing?

EDIT:  My current suspicion is a stack-allocated array: I declare a pointer to double (stack), then assign to it the result of a function that returns double *.  Then I memmove it to a previously allocated place.

I can't memmove, memcpy or assign a stack variable then hope it will persist, can I?

Comment: Can we see some more code? Maybe age_dep.c

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have since found that this valgrind error

```
Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
```

happens all the time and is not the source of the error.  It appears to be a red herring in most cases I've encountered since posting this question.

Comment: Joel, no, it's never a red herring, and you should always fix it. It's potentially an extremely serious bug (although occasionally harmless).

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what the problem is, but

```
-track-origins=yes
```

might help get you more information about what it's complaining about; see this blog post for details:
http://blog.mozilla.com/nnethercote/2009/02/27/eliminating-undefined-values-with-valgrind-the-easy-way/

Comment: I'm using track-origins; I forgot to mention that.  Could it be leading me astray?

Answer (score 0):

possible reason:
  you define `age_dep_data->mtable` as `double*`
  but it should be `double**` to be an array of arrays

Comment: Is it what I'm doing?  I allocate an array of size n*(size of a pointer to double), then for each pointer in that array I allocate an array of size m*(size of a double).  Do I need to use sizeof(double **) in the call to malloc()?

Comment: no, you code is okey; we can't see the declaration of age_dep_data->mtable - it should be declared as double**

Comment: It is declared as double ** within a structure (also dynamically allocated).